# Why was the question about Judaism's "evil" approach to women deleted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, moderation

On Feb 20, 2017 there was a question by someone asking about Judaism's "evil" treatment of women. Someone had even given a long, quality answer.

But now the question is gone - what happened to it?

Comment: I think that a certain question (alleging that the Talmud says that non-Jews are animals, allegedly written by a Muslim) is repeated posted to various stacks and then deleted. This deletion policy makes it hard to figure out what is going on with such posts.

Answer (score 5):

[That question](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80093)<sup>1</sup> was deleted by the community as being ["rude or abusive"](//judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). As [the quasi-official description](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035) says:

> The *rude or abusive* flag (formerly known as *offensive*) is meant to be used only in extreme cases, like hate speech, abuse against people, or abuse of the community or system.

For what it's worth, I agree with the community that this qualified.

For nonrude, nonabusive questions about women, see [women](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women).

---

<sup>1. [Viewable by users with 10K+ reputation score.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't call that question an "extreme" case in the league of "hate speech" or " abuse against people." Use of the word "hate" does not "hate speech" make. And there are other things to do with a poor question than delete it. Downvoting is one example.

Comment: What does it mean that "the community" deleted that question? I think this is a bit weaselly. Surely it was certain members, not the whole community. I, for one, did not delete it.

Comment: @SAH, I meant that the normal methods that the software allows for the members of a Stack  Exchange site to flag a question as "rude or abusive" (and thus delete it) were followed. Not that every single member deleted it.

Comment: Thanks. That is, somebody (maybe a moderator) flagged the question and then a moderator deleted it?

Comment: Not necessarily, @SAH. [Any answer that accumulates enough offensive or spam flags will be automatically deleted.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I certainly don't think that question fell into that flag category. It was certainly a bit ignorant, but it's a common claim, and it's good that these questions can be addressed seriously - as it was.

Comment: @DAE, there's nothing wrong with an appropriate question on the same topic. That question, the way it was asked, fell into that flag category, in my own opinion and that of whoever flagged it.

Comment: I think that question was valuable in that it's a good example of דע מה להשיב, ומענה רך משיב חמה....

Comment: @SAH I posted it [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4239/472); please copy it and flag when you're done so I can delete it.

Comment: @SAH I briefly viewed the question, but don't recall its contents. I, therefore, have to infer its severity. Your answer is a great analysis. Within the bigger picture, BTW, the discriminatory claim against women is similar to the arguments that Judaism discriminates against Gentiles. I hear this argument often when Gentiles read the words of *Aleinu*. It's an "old" argument. People who make this claim as well as the one who posed the original question in the tone that it was, have already made up their minds & prob. aren't really interested in your answer, unfortunately. Happy Adar.

Comment: @DanF Thanks very much for your kind words! I'd be interested in seeing an apologetics here for the two lines in "Aleinu," because I don't either understand why they're not--perhaps a bit--unjust.  ... I think these answers are worth writing because people both inside and outside of religious Judaism may be justifiably very troubled, and even kept from observance (or from love of Jews), by such things if they don't understand them.

Comment: @SAH Agreed. However, as stated, sometimes, hatred is quite apparent, as it prob. was in that deleted question. That's when, I think, answering the question is unwarranted. It doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @SAH Thank you for your diligence in following through to provide a good home for your answer. Your post is now linked on the sidebar of SE sites across the network, as part of the [HNQ list](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), and is getting hundreds of views.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks so much Isaac Moses; it makes me feel really good